# Dynamic google charts

Tags: objective-c, charts, google-visualization

well i got this code:

```
NSLog(@"button pressed");
    NSString* myurl=@"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=bg,s,67676700&chs=300x225&cht=p&chd=s:Uf9a&chdl=30°|40°|50°|60°";
    NSString *theurl=[myurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theurl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                        timeoutInterval:60.0];                                              

    NSURLResponse* response;
    NSError* error;
    NSData *imageData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",error); 
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
    NSLog(@"%@",imageData); 

    UIImage *myimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    graphimage.image=myimage;
```

Nothing realy special there...
but when i request the url: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=bg,s,67676700&chs=300x225&cht=p&chd=s:Uf9a&chdl=30°|40°|50°|60°

it requests with degrees like 30/40/50 ... but i want values and not degreses in there which i get from the database.., how can i do it?

Comment: Hi Emre, is there a place with some examples of google charts for objective c, like you have here?

Comment: Luda you can check https://developers.google.com/chart for some examples! And you can use the technique above in my question to show it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to just get the degrees from a database and store them in a collection. Then you will be able to loop over the collection and add them to the string.

```
//Get Degrees from database, store them in an array of NSNumbers
...
//Pretend these are from a db
NSArray *degreesFromDatabase = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:35],
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:50],
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:25],
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:72],
                                    nil];
    //URL with all static content
    NSMutableString *myurl = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=bg,s,67676700&chs=300x225&cht=p&chd=s:Uf9a&chdl="];

    int count = [degreesFromDatabase count];

    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        NSNumber *degree = [degreesFromDatabase objectAtIndex:i];
        [myurl appendFormat:@"%@%%C2%%B0", degree];
        if(i < count - 1)
            [myurl appendString:@"|"];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function that receive all the necessary parameters, creates a google chart and converts it to a `UIImage`.

[image]

Here it is:

> -(UIImage *)produceGoogleChartImage:(NSString*)title
>
> ```
>                            xAxis:(NSArray*)axisXLabels
>                           yAxis:(NSArray*)axisYLabels
>                         andData:(NSArray*)dataValues
>                           color:(NSString*)lineColor
>                      chartWidth:(NSNumber*)width
>                      chartHight:(NSNumber*)hight
>                     lagendLabel:(NSString*)legend
>                        minScale:(NSNumber*)minScale
>                        maxScale:(NSNumber*)maxScale{
>
> NSMutableString *myurl = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chxl=0:|"];
>
>
> //axisXLabels
> int countAxisXLabels = [axisXLabels count];
>
> for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < countAxisXLabels; ++i)
> {
>     NSNumber *value = [axisXLabels objectAtIndex:i];
>     [myurl appendFormat:@"%@", value];
>     if(i < countAxisXLabels - 1)
>         [myurl appendString:@"|"];
> }
>
> [myurl appendString:@"|1:|"];
>
>
> //axisYLabels
>  int countAxisYLabels = [axisYLabels count];
> for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < countAxisYLabels; ++i)
> {
>     NSNumber *value = [axisYLabels objectAtIndex:i];
>     [myurl appendFormat:@"%@", value];
>     if(i < countAxisYLabels - 1)
>         [myurl appendString:@"|"];
> }
>
> [myurl appendString:@"&chxr=0,0,105|1,3.333,100&chxt=x,y&chs="];
>
> //size
> [myurl appendFormat:@"%@x%@&cht=lc&chd=t:", width,hight];
>
> //dataValues
> int countDataValues = [dataValues count];
>
> for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < countDataValues; ++i)
> {
>     NSNumber *value = [dataValues objectAtIndex:i];
>     [myurl appendFormat:@"%@", value];
>     if(i < countDataValues - 1)
>     [myurl appendString:@","];
> }
>
> //legend
> [myurl appendFormat:@"&chdl=%@&chg=25,50&chls=2&",legend];
>
> //color
> [myurl appendFormat:@"chm=o,%@,0,-2,8&chco=%@",lineColor,lineColor];
>
> //title
> [myurl appendFormat:@"&chtt=+%@",title];
>
> //scale
> [myurl appendFormat:@"&chds=%@,%@",minScale,maxScale];
>
>
>
> NSString *theurl=[myurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>
> NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theurl]
> ```
>
> cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
>                                                           timeoutInterval:60.0];
>
> ```
> NSURLResponse* response;
> NSError* error;
> NSData *imageData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response
> ```
>
> error:&error];
>       NSLog(@"%@",error);
>       NSLog(@"%@",response);
>       NSLog(@"%@",imageData);
>
> ```
> UIImage *myimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
>
>
> return myimage;
>
> // Chart Wizard: https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard
>  }
> ```

And here is the test function:

> -(void)test{
>
> ```
> NSString* title = @"Height History";
> NSArray *axisXLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
>                        @"Jan",
>                        @"Feb",
>                        @"Mar",
>                        @"Jun",
>                        @"Jul",
>                        @"Aug",
>                        nil];
>
>
> NSArray *axisYLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
>                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
>                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:50],
>                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:150],
>                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:200],
>                         nil];
>
> NSArray *dataValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
>                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:130],
>                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:140],
>                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:140],
>                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:150],
>                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:170],
>                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:180],
>                        nil];
>
> NSString *lineColor = @"FF9900";
>
> NSNumber *width = [NSNumber numberWithInt:300];
>
> NSNumber *hight = [NSNumber numberWithInt:200];
>
> NSNumber *minScale = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
>
> NSNumber *maxScale = [NSNumber numberWithInt:200];
>
> NSString *legendLabel = @"cm";
>
> UIImage *myimage =[self produceGoogleChartImage:title xAxis:axisXLabels yAxis:axisYLabels andData:dataValues color:lineColor
> ```
>
> chartWidth:width chartHight:hight lagendLabel:legendLabel
>   minScale:minScale maxScale:maxScale];
>
> ```
> _chartImage.image=myimage;
> ```
>
> }

You should get image, like the one in the question.

Comment: I found an answer to my question a long time ago! But this can be helpfull to other people, thnx!